# Extracting text from a html file?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a web page which contains a bunch of text and I want to extract just the text from the page and write it to a file.  I am trying to use BeautifulSoup but am not sure it easily does what I want.  Here is the story:  I believe that the text I want to extract lies between:

```
<td colspan="2" class="msg_text_cell" style="text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(212, 225, 245); background-image: none; background-repeat: repeat-x;" rowspan="2" valign="top" width="100%">
```

and

```
<p></p><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 550px; height: 48px;">
```

What I want to do is the select just the text lines between, but no including the above begin and end text.  Note that the begin html above is on a line by itself but the end text sometimes occurs just after the last text I want but is not on a new line.

I can not seem to see how to do what I want with BeautifulSoup, but probably it is my unfamiliarity getting in the way.

Also, the text I want to extract occurs say 50 times in the page, so I want all such text separated by something like '+++++++++++++++++++++' to make it easier to read.

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: I screwed up in that the begin text did not get pasted.  Here is begin text:     <td colspan="2" class="msg_text_cell" style="text-align: justify;" rowspan="2" valign="top" width="100%"> and here is the end text: <p></p><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 550px; height: 48px;">

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without more context. Could you provide a link to the web page or a sample of html and then specify exactly what you are trying to extract?

Answer (score 0):

If ever you know a notch of Ruby, i can point you to Nokogiri which is an amazing gem for screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

simply put you can loop over expected dom elements that contain the text you want and extract it that way ... using jquery something like $('td.msg_text_cell').each( function (idx,el) {
idx would be the index in the array of jQuery objects found from the selector above getting all tds with a class of msg_text_cell ... 
})

you can do with native js also so don't think that i'm pushing jquery ... just a framework i'm more familiar with

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with  BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = "<td colspan=\"2\" class=\"msg_text_cell\" style=\"text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(212, 225, 245); background-image: none; background-repeat: repeat-x;\" rowspan=\"2\" valign=\"top\" width=\"100%\"> <p>The text</p><div style=\"overflow: hidden; width: 550px; height: 48px;\">"
soup = bs(soup)
soup.find('p')
```

You can now found something like the text inside the

tag

```
Output: <p>The text</p>
```

You can now add loop to modify the variable.

Then you can save in a file.

```
with open("data.csv","w") as tW:
writer = csv.writer(tW,delimiter=",")
writer.writerow(["Ptag"])
for i in soup:
    p = i.get_text()
    writer.writerow([p])
```